# Problems when pasting a monetary value in a TDBEdit

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I created a DBEditValida component that descends from a DBEdit that receives monetary values, the formatting of the component itself (#,##0.00) is working fine. But when I copy and paste a number with a dot (example: 1,000.00) the component gives the error "IS NOT A BCD VALUE". The dot must remain in the formatting of the component values.

I'm trying to treat it in two different ways:

1. I tried to handle formatting when exiting the component.

```
procedure TDBEditValida.DoExit;
var text_formata : string;
var num_conv : real;
begin
 inherited;
 if text <> '' then
  begin

    num_conv := StrToFloat(StringReplace(text,'.','', [rfreplaceall]));
    text_formata := Formatfloat('#,##0.00',num_conv);
    text := text_formata;

  end
end;

{but when I try to save the form it gives the same error "IS NOT A BCD VALUE".}
```

2. handle the copied value on the clipboard.

```
procedure TDBEditValida.DoEnter;
begin
  inherited;
  Clipboard.AsText := StringReplace(Clipboard.AsText,'.','', [rfreplaceall]);
end;

...

procedure TDBEditValida.Change;

begin
  inherited;
  Clipboard.AsText := StringReplace(Clipboard.AsText,'.','', [rfreplaceall]);
end;

{when I copy the value and select the component, the formatting is correct, but if I select the component and then copy the value, it still shows an error}
```

Comment: Change the order of your `inherited` call to be after you format the text. You see calling `inherited` executes the `DoExit` method from the parent class. So in your case the `inherited` call should be after you have formatted the text.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I tried the following ways and it didn't work:

    inherited;
    num_conv := StrToFloat(StringReplace(text,'.','', [rfreplaceall]));
    text_formata := Formatfloat('#,##0.00',num_conv);
    text := text_formata;

    num_conv := StrToFloat(StringReplace(text,'.','', [rfreplaceall]));
    inherited;
    text_formata := Formatfloat('#,##0.00',num_conv);
    text := text_formata;

    num_conv := StrToFloat(StringReplace(text,'.','', [rfreplaceall]));
    text_formata := Formatfloat('#,##0.00',num_conv);
    inherited;
    text := text_formata;

Comment: You tried all but the correct way. `Inherited` must be called after you have changed your component `Text` property to reflect the desired formatting. In your case this would be after **if** clause.

Comment: I tried the following and it keeps giving error:

Comment: if text <> '' then
  begin
    num_conv := StrToFloat(StringReplace(text,'.','', [rfreplaceall]));
    text_formata := Formatfloat('#,##0.00',num_conv);
    text := text_formata;
  end;

  inherited;

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't know what is causing your error. Also I don't have Delphi 7 installed to go and test it out.